# REST Looking for the last created / updated documents in 24h for all workspaces

Tags: search, rest, api

I am looking for a solution to get all the created / updated documents for the last 24h for all my workspaces.

How is it possible via REST API? Like an Activity Feed.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Its about SP2013

Comment: Using search you can get he documents you have access to, provided you are crawling the content an your index is fresh.

Comment: Yeah, but i diddn't find a solution via REST to get all my modified documents in the last 24h, how is it possible like htts://mydomain.com/_api/search/.....

Comment: First you have to get the query working. Have you tried using your search center to query for the documents? Something like "IsDocument=1 Write=today" or you could use > and < to actually capture the previous 24 hour period. Once you have it working in the search center then just add it to your REST query.

Comment: I tried this, but it doen't work, i get Error 400: _api/search/query?querytext='ContentType:Factsheet RMExpiryDate>2014-05-30'&rowlimit=500&SelectProperties='RMExpiryDate,fileExtension,filename,ContentType'"

Comment: Does that query work in the search center? Does any query against the managed property RMExpiryDate work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
https://domain.ltd/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='write:range(2016-06-13T12:30:00.0000000Z,max,from="ge")'
```